# Cambiar el tipo de marcador en marcadores multiples

Tags: javascript, google-maps-v3

Siguiendo la documentación de Google Maps, llegué a poder importar los datos desde una BD de mysql. 
Hasta logré poder aplicar el análisis del tipo de marcador y le agrega etiquetas a los marcadores, como se ve en la imagen inferior.

[image: IMAGENES]

Ahora bien, me gustaría quitar esa etiqueta, y poner pines diferentes. Las etiquetas las defino en la siguiente rutina al iniciar el script de js:

```
var customLabel = {
    1: {
      label: 'S'
    },
    2: {
      label: 'E'
    },
    3: {
      label: 'M'
    },
    4: {
      label: 'T'
    },
  };
```

el marcador se arma en la siguiente rutina:

```
var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
```

Yo podría en esa misma rutina donde defino que ponga la letra S si el valor es 1, ..., etc elegir el tipo de icono a mostrar ?
Intenté seguir la documentación de Google maps sobre los tipos de marcadores, pero sin resultados... 
Alguien podrá darme una mano ? 
El customLabel lo armo a partir de un campo de la base que tiene los valores 1, 2, 3, ... Etc

Me gustaría usar estos iconos
[image: iconos]

---

CODIGO QUE TENGO EN LA PAGINA:

TABLA DESDE DONDE TOMO LOS DATOS:

```
CREATE TABLE `markers` (
 `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `tipo` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
 `lat` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `lng` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `descripcion` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 `realizo` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `idtipo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

CODIGO PRINCIPAL DE LA PAGINA QUE CARGA LOS DATOS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Mapa de Google Maps</title>
<style>
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 800px; height:500px;"></div>

<script>
  var customLabel = {
    1: {
      label: 'S'
    },
    2: {
      label: 'E'
    },
    3: {
      label: 'M'
    },
    4: {
      label: 'T'
    },
  };

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.609555, -58.388772),
      zoom: 10
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      downloadUrl('resultado.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
          var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
          var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
            parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = address
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            label: icon.label
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });
      });
    }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>

<input type="text" name="lat" value="">
<input type="text" name="lng" value="">
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*******YOUR API KEY***********&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CODIGO DEL ARCHIVO resultado.php donde levanto la información de la base de datos:

```
<?php
 session_start(); //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente
 require '../../includes/conexion.php';
 include '../../includes/funcs_pdo.php';

 function parseToXML($htmlStr){
  $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
  $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr);
  $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);
  $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
  $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr);
  return $xmlStr;
 }

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$conexion = new Conexion();
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT id, tipo, lat, lng, descripcion, idtipo FROM markers WHERE visible=1 ORDER BY id DESC");
$stmt->execute();

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, echo parent node
echo '<markers>';

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
  while($row_markers=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   echo '<marker ';
   echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row_markers['tipo']) . '" ';
   echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row_markers['descripcion']) . '" ';
   echo 'lat="' . $row_markers['lat'] . '" ';
   echo 'lng="' . $row_markers['lng'] . '" ';
   echo 'type="' . $row_markers['idtipo'] . '" ';
   echo '/>';
  }
 }
 // End XML file
 echo '</markers>';
```

toda esta información aparece en la documentación de Google Maps y yo lo adapte con mi conexión a la base de datos y el resultado de esto es el mapa que aparece en la imagen superior.

Comment: Puedes ir directamente a la documentación https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers?hl=es

Comment: Ya intenté seguir los pasos pero no pude resolverlo

Comment: ¿Puedes crear un [mcve] (sin poner tu clave de api)?

Comment: Pongo todo el código que tengo y que devuelve lo que está en la imagen de arriba

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ahí pegué todo el código que tengo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label
      });
```

Estás fijando el atributo `label` que es el texto que ves en tu mapa, pero estás omitiendo el atributo `icon` y por eso todos se dibujan con el ícono por defecto. Podrías hacer:

```
var customLabel = {
    1: {
      label: 'S',
      url: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'
    },
    2: {
      label: 'E',
      url: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png'
    },
    3: {
      label: 'M',
      url: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
    },
    4: {
      label: 'T',
      url: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
    },
  };
```

Y luego:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label,
        icon: icon.url
      });
```

Comment: EXCELENTE !!! MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS @amenadiel !!!... igual creo que los iconos que elegí son horribles jajajajajaja

Answer (score 0):

Revisando los datos que tienes almacenados y como deseas mostrarlos te dejo el siguiente fragmento para que lo adaptes de acuerdo a tu conveniencia.

Este ejemplo muestra la devolución de un formato Json para hacerlo mas dinámico.

```
$.each(data.mensaje, function(i, item){
//Obteniendo las coordenadas del punto
var posi = new google.maps.LatLng(item.mapa_latitud, item.mapa_longitud);//La posicion del marcador.

var testtitle = item.nombreubicacion;
var etiqueta = item.etiqueta;
//Ruta de la imagen
var iconocliente = 'img/cliente.png';//Obteniendo de directorio local
/*Proveedor de iconos en este caso la direccion que proporciona google*/
var iconoproveedor = 'https://png.icons8.com/street-view/nolan/60';//Aqui escribe la url de google dependiendo de la imagen que necesites, puedes cambiar por un switch en vez del condicional IF. (http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_green.png)
//cambiar etiqueta
if(etiqueta == "C"){
    etiqueta = "C";
    icono=iconocliente;
}
else{
    etiqueta = "P";
    icono=iconoproveedor;
}
// Leer las propiedades del marcador
var marca = new google.maps.Marker({
    idMarcador:item.mapa_id,
    position:posi,
    clieID:item.cliente_id,
    cx:item.mapa_latitud,
    cy:item.mapa_longitud,
    lugar:item.nombre_ubicacion,
    title:testtitle,
    whois:item.nombreubicacion,
    map:mapa,
    icon:icono//Renderizar propiedad segun corresponda.
});
```

Captura de ejemplo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]